# Android: Retrieve layout_marginBottom programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout

In my a LinearLayout I have set `android:layout_marginBottom` in my XML. I just want to retrieve that value.

Just `LayoutParams` doesn't give me access to `bottomMargin` . I tried to typecast :

```
row1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainrow1); 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams row1Params = (android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams) row1.getLayoutParams();
```

but this gives me Runtime exception ClassCastException.

The main aim is I got buttons in nested LinearLayouts & I want to set height/width of LinearLayout programmatically that will inturn auto set height of buttons. I have added bottomMargin after 1st layout - so there is space between 2 rows.

Comment: @jitendrasharma, Yes jitendra, that did the job. I have 3 btns in a Horizontal LinearLayout. At present I have set value to layout_width="78dip". I want it to use all the space available. If I put "WRAP_CONTENT" then only the size of text is the width of the btn. I want all btns of the row to be of same size & utilize all the width soace availble. Height is fine as I have used "fill_parent" for layout_height. Is there anything to set for width that will do the trick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Your layout of Button according to following logic,

set Layout_Width to 0dip
set Layout_Weight to 1
set Layout_Height to Wrap_Content

Comment: for layout_height - fill_parent works rather than wrap_content. But facing a problem with it. Have a look at the updated question.

Comment: Please let me know if you are still facing problem or it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks but that wraping & filling problem is solved. Now I am not able to find height of an layout in onCreate() - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784616/android-get-screen-size-for-the-root-layout-only   See if you can guide with this.

Answer (score 0):

try this. When you get layout,  R.layout.  is best option. It is working for me.

```
  row1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.mainrow1);
```

Comment: In your code it is R.id.mainrow1 not R.layout.mainrow1. Please refer your posted code first line in findViewById method.

Comment: @thinksteep, jitendrasharma's option clean & build did the work. Thnaks